# Nodejs Mongodb: findByIdAndUpdate not returning correct error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My put request is returning success when it should be returning an error. I do not even have a `User` collection in my MongoDb yet (therefore no valid id's either). But when I make this call it returns `success`. Why is findByIdAndUpdate not returning any error?

```
    app.put(path, (req, res) => {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, req.body, {}, (err, doc) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
            res.status(200).send({ response: 'success' });
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.put(path, (req, res) => {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, req.body, {}, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    } else {
        if(doc){
            return res.status(200).send({ response: 'success' });
        } else {
            return res.status(400).send({response:'false',message:'Not Found!'});
        }
    }
  });
});
```

By default, when no matching document found, mongoose return `null` and we need to do something with that `null` value.

Comment: Thank you that is a prefect answer! And I now understand it better, thank you. One small tip question please: findByIdAndUpdate console.log's and item, how can I stop it from logging an item automatically? (if you don't know no worries, was just hoping you could help out quickly)

Comment: Yeah I was just waiting for the 5min delay before I can accept it as an answer haha! :)